# how to clear webstorage in typescript like javascript

Tags: typescript

This is my javascript code ,

```
var _storage = typeof (Storage) !== "undefined";

if (_storage ) {
    sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

I want to write this code in typescript, I found [ng2plus library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng2plus/web-storage) and still don't know it's best option ?

Comment: If the same code doesn't work, please give us the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

works in typescript as well.

Here is the full documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

I believe "sessionStorage" should be a global constant when it is available. Simply checking whether it is defined should do:

```
if (sessionStorage !== undefined) {
     sessionStorage.clear();
} else {
     // Session storage is not available.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript you are encouraged to be more explicit. What is this `sessionStorage` object? Where is it coming from?

In short the following should work:

```
if (window.sessionStorage !== undefined) {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

Notice how you need to explicitly say that it is in the `window` global. The ensure that the compiler recognises that the `window` global will exist you need to be including `dom` in `lib` under your [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)